# Trying to make a menu driven interface for maintaining a list of scores

Tags: python, menu

I'm trying to make a menu driven interface that maintains a list of scores. After selecting 3 and adding a score to the list, I click 4 on the menu and it gives this error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

menu = """
Scoring Engine:

1: Exit
2: List scores so far
3: Add scores
4: Display the highest and lowest scores

```
scores = [85.30, 85.20, 21.99]

done = False

while not done:

    print(menu)

    selection = input('Please enter a selection between 1 and 4: ')
    print()

    if selection == '1':
        done = True
    elif selection == '2':
        print()
        for score in scores:
            print('Scores recorded so far: {:.2f}'.format(float(score)))
    elif selection == '3':
        print()
        addScore = input('Please enter a score between 0 and 100: ')
        scores.extend(addScore)
    elif selection == '4':
        print('Highest Score: ', max(scores))
        print('Lowest Score: ', min(scores))
    else:
        print()
        print('{} Invalid entry. Please enter a selection
1,2,3,4'.format(menu))
```

Answer (score 2):

In each instance of the `input()` method, you will need to convert the user input from a string to a int or float. So instead of:

```
addScore = input('Please enter a score between 0 and 100: ')
    scores.extend(addScore)
```

you would need something like:

```
addScore = int(input('Please enter a score between 0 and 100: '))
    scores.extend(addScore)
```

or:

```
addScore = input('Please enter a score between 0 and 100: ')
    scores.extend(int(addScore))
```

Comment: try to format your answer by selecting the python script lines and then press on "{}" button

Comment: Ok. Thank you Mahmound